# Set transparent theme but custom style to activity on Android

Tags: android, android-theme

In my App, I am doing theme change and it's going to apply to all activities.
But what i wants to set transparent theme to one my activity but also wants to set style from theme which selected for another activities except this(one who have transparent theme)

below method shows how theme change happens

```
 public static void onActivityCreateSetTheme(Activity activity, int theme) {
    switch (theme) {
        case DEFAULT_THEME: {
            activity.setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
            break;
        }
        case THEMEPINK: {
            activity.setTheme(R.style.AppThemePink);
            break;
        }
        case THEMERED: {
            activity.setTheme(R.style.AppThemeRed);
            break;
        }
        case THEMEBLUE: {
            activity.setTheme(R.style.AppThemeBlue);
            break;
        }
        case THEMEGREEN: {
            activity.setTheme(R.style.AppThemeGreen);
            break;
        }
        case THEME_TRANSPARENT:
            activity.setTheme(R.style.Transparent);
            break;
    }
}
```

How can i set style from selected theme to activity with transparent theme?

Comment: Do you want keep transparent theme to a specific activity no matter which theme is selected?

Comment: yes i want keep activity transparent  but need to change primary colour from for activity. 
currently only activity appears with transparent theme but with default colours and not the colours which i had applied from activity.